# Length ( number of methods ) of a class code and performance

Tags: oop, java

What kind of dependency is between number of methods, or length of source code of a class to performance (memory usage, speed of execution )? It is better to create as simple class as possible, or I can implement as may function as I want to one class? Does Java load whole class to memory, when object is accessed by interfaces?

Comment: I think, your question is really contextual with performance of a class with number of methods one contains, but given answers do not satisfy the query, instead, those are describing other aspects of performance. I am still expecting correct answer (also if you own have got yet from somewhere else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking about it for the *completely* wrong reason.

Forget about performance. It does not matter in this question. At all.

Huge classes are very bad because they are hard to maintain. They're hard to understand, probably violate the Single Responsibility Principle massively or even harbor duplicated code.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of parts to your question but performance and class size usually shouldn't be talked about together. Make small classes because it's easier to maintain and debug.

Classes (class code) are loaded into memory when they are referenced for the first time, or maybe sooner depending on the class loader but this is *usually* a small price compared to actually executing your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java loads the whole class into memory. But it's probably not the *class* that consumes most memory, but rather the number of *instances* of it.

I'd say that except for extreme cases, there is little or no correlation between the lengthes and number of methods in your classes and memory usage in runtine.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU, the number of methods in a class (or more accurately the size of the class) will only affect the loading time.